# How to avoid charset change after form submittion in symfony 1.1?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, symfony1

I have page which with charset as UTF-8 once I submitt the page will load same page to show error messages if I have any, but after page submittion the japanese text which I have in page is not decoding properly it is showing some encoding strings. I will redirect to this page using $this->forward, and I have charset=UTF-8 in meta tag.

Comment: It's possible you have double-encoding. Could you provide an example of the input and the resulting output?

Comment: @CraigMason : Here is the resulting output of Japanese text " æ°åã‚’å…¥åŠ›ã—ã¦ä¸‹ã•ã„ã€‚".

Comment: That looks partially like latin-1 output as utf-8 but there are some broken characters. Perhaps you could load a full page, file -> save as, then upload that?

Comment: @CraigMason : You mean I need to upload my file here ?? Is there any such option here ?